# How can i write this without using the if statment

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def in_puzzle_horizontal(puzzle, word):

    left_right = lr_occurrences(puzzle, word)
    right_left = lr_occurrences((rotate_puzzle(rotate_puzzle(puzzle))), word) 
    total = left_right or right_left

    if total > 0:
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: why not just `return total > 0`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to code review.

Answer (score 6):

You only have to replace the if statement by:

```
return total > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
left_right = lr_occurrences(puzzle, word)
right_left = lr_occurrences((rotate_puzzle(rotate_puzzle(puzzle))), word)
total = left_right or right_left
return total > 0
```